# Wpf Data Trigger Value can be Generic Type?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, binding

I have wpf data trigger as below.

```
   <DataTrigger Value="0" Binding="{Binding Path=TestDirection,Mode=OneWay}">
                        <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                            <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource LastDonePrice_UpTickDirection_Blink}"/>
                        </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger  Value="2" Binding="{Binding Path=TestDirection,Mode=OneWay}">
                        <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                            <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource LastDonePrice_DownTickDirection_Blink}" />
                        </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                    </DataTrigger>
```

TestDirection is the property of Generic Type returning '0' or '2'. I want to animate the storyboard based on this values. But It's not working now. Please advise. Thanks.

Comment: take a look at the last example of http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.datatrigger.aspx

Comment: In general there are not problems. Can you provide more details?

Comment: Is a PropertyChanged event fired for TestDirection?

Comment: @IVerzin Yeah, data trigger is working. it's just that behind wcf is not passing 0 and 2 to my binding class. Sorry to trouble everyone.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a Value Converter while binding "TestDirection" and value converter will return a boolean value if that generic type is 0 or 2....

some thing like this...

```
<DataTrigger  Value="true" Binding="{Binding Path=TestDirection,Converter={StaticResource <Converter>},Mode=OneWay}">
```